# Impelementing SCD type 2 in Palantir code repository

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, palantir-foundry

I have a requirement to implement the SCD type 2 logic using palantir code repository. If anyone has tried implementing it, can you please help me with the reference links please.
I've implemented it in SQL server, but the ask here is to implement it in Palantir

Answer (score -1):

You can use SQL in Foundry's Code Repositories. So if you're already implemented this logic once in SQL Server, what you need to do is translate that same logic into the SparkSQL dialect in a file in a Code Repository. At that point it depends on your familiarity with SparkSQL. There are a lot of SparkSQL docs and tutorials online. Also, if it's permitted by your employer, translating SQL Server syntax to SparkSQL syntax is something that tools like ChatGPT are pretty darn good at.